# how to redirect root directory alias to a document_root subfloder in lighttpd?

Tags: alias, lighttpd

I have this directory configuration:

```
htdocs/www -> web site pages
htdocs/WEB-INF -> lib and classes, used in web pages
htdocs/data -> data (images, documents)
```

This is how I do it, with apache:

```
htdocs/www/images/logo.gif
htdocs/www/exemple/php:
<?
include_once $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/lib/classes/A.class.php";
$s=file_get_contents($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/data/content.txt");
?>
<a href="/images/logo.gif">
```

this is part of my lighttpd conf, mimicking Apache httpd.conf:
alias.url = ("/" => ".../htdocs/www/")
server.document-root = ".../htdocs"

Unfortunately, $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] is pointing to htdocs/www, instead of  htdocs.

How can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you solved this by now, but if not:

Open `/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf` and edit the value assigned to `{server.document-root}`.

You should fill out the **full path** to your webroot. Do not forget to restart lighttpd.